# How to use type annotation to support generic subtypes for third party classes in pydantic basemodels?

Tags: python, numpy, python-typing, pydantic

Going from the [pydantic documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/types/#handling-third-party-types) I have written the following annotation wrapper for numpy arrays in order to parse numpy arrays from jsons directly:

```py
from typing import Annotated, Any

import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt
from pydantic import (
    GetCoreSchemaHandler,
    GetJsonSchemaHandler,
)
from pydantic.json_schema import JsonSchemaValue
from pydantic_core import core_schema


class _NumpyPydanticAnnotation:
    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(
        cls,
        _source_type: Any,
        _handler: GetCoreSchemaHandler,
    ) -> core_schema.CoreSchema:
        def valdidate_from_lists(value: list) -> np.ndarray:
            result = np.array(value)
            return result

        from_list_schema = core_schema.chain_schema(
            [
                core_schema.list_schema(),
                core_schema.no_info_plain_validator_function(valdidate_from_lists),
            ]
        )

        return core_schema.json_or_python_schema(
            json_schema=from_list_schema,
            python_schema=core_schema.union_schema(
                [
                    # check if it's an instance first before doing any further work
                    core_schema.is_instance_schema(np.ndarray),
                    from_list_schema,
                ]
            ),
            serialization=core_schema.plain_serializer_function_ser_schema(
                lambda instance: instance.tolist()
            ),
        )

    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_json_schema__(
        cls, _core_schema: core_schema.CoreSchema, handler: GetJsonSchemaHandler
    ) -> JsonSchemaValue:
        # Use the same schema that would be used for `list`
        return handler(core_schema.list_schema())


NumpyWrapper = Annotated[npt.NDArray, _NumpyPydanticAnnotation]
```

Although the validation could be extended to be more thorough, this can be used in Basemodels as follows:

```py
class SomeDataModel(BaseModel):
    my_awesome_array: NumpyWrapper
```

Which works fine, however I want to support validation for the correct dtype as well:

```py
class SomeDataModel(BaseModel):
    my_awesome_array: NumpyWrapper[np.float64]
```

I initially this would work with generic, something like

```py
dtypelike = TypeVar("dtypelike", bound=npt.DTypeLike)


class _NumpyPydanticAnnotation(Generic[dtypelike]):
    ... # class content
```

But this results in the error message

> Type "ndarray[Any, dtype[Unknown]]" is already specialized

when used as described above. I am a bit stuck on how to use it. Additionally I would like to check the correct dtype in the `validate_from_lists` function.

Comment: Do you actually care about the correct JSON schema? Or just about the serialization?

Comment: You might want to checkout https://github.com/caniko/pydantic-numpy for inspiration

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about the actual JOSN schema, you could just work with an annotated type, setting `arbitrary_types_allowed=True` and define a `__class_getitem__` to support the parametrization, along the lines of:

```py
import numpy as np
from typing import Annotated
from pydantic import PlainSerializer, BeforeValidator, ConfigDict, BaseModel
from functools import partial


class NumpyArray:
    """Numpy array type"""
    @staticmethod
    def validate(value, dtype):
        return np.array(value, dtype=dtype)

    @staticmethod
    def serialize(value):
        return value.tolist()
    
    def __class_getitem__(cls, item):
        validate = partial(cls.validate, dtype=item)
        return Annotated[np.ndarray, PlainSerializer(cls.serialize), BeforeValidator(validate)]


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(arbitrary_types_allowed=True)
    a: NumpyArray[int]
    b: NumpyArray[np.complex64]

m = MyModel(a=[1.2, 3.8, 3.2], b=[1, 2, 3])
assert m.b.dtype == np.complex64
m.model_dump()
```

This prints:

```
{'a': [1, 3, 3], 'b': [(1+0j), (2+0j), (3+0j)]}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the interesting approach. Unfortunately I need use and work with the  JSON schema in my case, also setting `arbitrary_types_allowed=True` is something I want to avoid in my case.